# Make a app that can off or on OTG by one click

Tags: javascript, android, usb-otg

I want create a app that can on off OTG.
It like the picture [OTG connection On or Off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEydB.jpg). But how can I do?? My code language is java and I am using Android studio

Comment: OTG is a apparently a web service and API? You show zero code attempt nor do you show references on documentation that you yourself have researched. Ok, so I should research it then "imagine" what your code looks like? I am not going to research it and solve what the documentation says to do, on a zero code attempt.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.